# Filter Foreach by boolean value in view

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, view, foreach

I need to be able to filter by a boolean field in my view for my foreach.  Here is the code I tried:

```
@foreach (var item in Model.TicketNotes.Reverse() while (item.PublicFlag==false))
```

If you remove everything after the while it works (minus the filtering out of course.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using Linq

```
 Model.TicketNotes.Reverse().Where(i => i.PublicFlag == false)
```

Comment: You could use `TakeWhile()` to match the desired behavior more closely.